# Kafka Producer Access to Kafka Error Codes

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am creating a service that will receive messages over http and publish them to a topic.  Using Spring for Apache Kafka, if any type of failure occurs which prevents a message from being published and acknowledged, an ExecutionException is caught containing nested KafkaProducerException and TimeoutExceptions (see below).

I feel that the exception messages are not providing details helpful for identifying root cause.  In the example exception output shown below it states that a record was expired because the threshold for **delivery.timeout.ms ?** had been reached.  At the same time my logs are getting filled with warning statements from the producer pointing more closely to the root cause "...Connection to node <#> could not be established.  Broker may not be available."

**How I am publishing:**

```
try {
    ListenableFuture<SendResult<Integer, String>> future = kafkaTemplate.send(topic, recordPartition, record.getKey(), record.getValue());
    SendResult myResult = future.get();
} 
catch (Exception e) {
}
```

**Example of Nested Exceptions**:

```
"java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaProducerException: Failed to send; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for testTopic-1:120001 ms has passed since batch creation."
```

**Example of Log Warnings from Producer:**

`WARN 152 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node 0 (<host>/<IP>:<PORT>) could not be established. Broker may not be available.`

**Questions:**

1. Is there a way for me to retrieve the [error codes from Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/protocol#protocol_error_codes) when my producer fails to publish a message successfully?
2. Is there a way for me to capture the warnings currently logged by the producer thread from org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient as they seem more descriptive and indicative of the actual underlying issue?
   **Example**: `WARN 152 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node 0 (<host>/<IP>:<PORT>) could not be established. Broker may not be available.`

Comment: I removed Spring from the title since this is all internal to the `KafkaProducer` code and there is nothing Spring can do to help.

Comment: @Gary Russell did you get answer for this

Comment: It was not my question; I only edited it to make it a bit more readable. See below - nobody has answered; I suggest you try to get an answer on one of the Apache Kafka mailing lists; if you get an answer, copy it here. https://kafka.apache.org/contact